# Mapping Windows Services back to Credential Management

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, credentials, service-account

In SharePoint 2010 Server, what service accounts do the following windows services map to in the Credential Management drop down?

- OSearch14(Windows Service)
- SPSearch4(Windows Service)

I am trying to resolve the below error from the TFS Best Practices Analyzer.

[image: Best Practices Analyzer Error]

When I open the Farm Credential Management, I see the following list of Services and Web Applications in the drop down list.

[image: Services and Web applications drop down from the Farm Credential Management]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct mapping is the following.

- SPSearch4 (Windows Service) → Windows Service - SharePoint Foundation Search
- OSearch14 (Windows Service) → Windows Service - SharePoint Server Search

Once I changed the accounts for each of these servers through the Farm Credential Management page, the error was resolved.